# Twitterログインを実装しているアプリが急に、動作しないとリジェクトされた

Tags: ios, twitter

私はエンジニアではありませんが、同僚の外国人エンジニアが解決の糸口が見つけられないため
こちらで質問させていただきます。

現在、運用しているiOSアプリでtwitterログインを実装しております。
今まで通常通り動いていたのですが
先日、appleにアップデートでサブミットしたところリジェクトを受けました。

内容は、twitterログインをタップすると(Musica)というアプリが開いてしまうというものでした。
テストフライトでもDEMOでも全て確認したのですが私たちではこの現象が確認できませんでした。

わかる方、もしくは経験されている方に質問ですが、このような場合はなにが怪しいと思われますか？

素人考えですと、
・APIの問題
・URLの問題
・ウイルス
・コードの問題
・アプリをチェックしているapple側のデバイスの問題

このどれかかなと思ったのですが、弊社のエンジニアはどれも当てはまらないといっていました。

このままですと、アプリがアップデートできず困ってしまいます。
どなたか、同様の経験があるもしくはほかのアイディアなどございましたら
助けていただけると非常に助かります。

専門的な回答で全く問題ございません。そのまま、英訳してエンジニアに確認するつもりです。

補足です
login code :

```
TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().logIn() { (session, error) in 
    if let session = session { }
}
```

authentication:

```
let key = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "consumerKey"),
secret = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "consumerSecret")
if let key = key as? String, let secret = secret as? String, !key.isEmpty && !secret.isEmpty {
    TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().start(withConsumerKey: key, consumerSecret: secret)
}
```

Comment: お困りのようですね。まず確認ですが、デバッグとしてインストールした端末では想定した通りにTwitterアプリや、WEBAuthなどの認証画面が出てきたという認識でよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: また、可能であれば、Twitter認証の部分のコードを展開いただけると回答がつきやすくなるかと思います（もちろんAPIKeyなどは伏せて）

Comment: @Sieg 様　ご回答ありがとうございます。デバッグとしてインストールした端末では想定した通りにTwitterアプリや、WEBAuthなどの認証画面が出てきたという認識で問題ございません。

Comment: @Sieg 様 コードを本文に追加いたしました。

Answer (score 1):

おそらくという回答になりますが、
レビュワーでのTwitterクライアントが独自のアプリが設定されているのでは無いでしょうか？

TwitterKitを利用しているものと考えますが、
iOS端末にアカウントを登録しているかしていないかで挙動が変わりますし、
デフォルトのTwitterクライアントに何をインストールしているかで開かれるアプリも変わるかと思います。
（またWEBで開いてもアクセスポイントでプロキシが設定されていたりすると
Twitterのサイトが出なかったりとかするかと…）

Appleのレビューにて動作が再現できないことは多々あります。
（例えば自位置や移動距離などで何かを取得するようなアプリや、
利用者が増えてから本領を発揮するアプリなど）
その際には、一通りの動作を撮影した動画をYoutubeなどで限定公開にし、
URLをレビュワーに共有し、正常時の動作を共有すると良いかと思います。

その上でレビュワーさんにどのような画面が出たかスクリーンショットなど送っていただくのはありかと……

Comment: @Sieg様　
ご丁寧に回答ありがとうございます。再度、申請したところやはりリジェクトを受けました。
アドバイスの動作の動画を共有して再度申請してみます。

ただ、一つ疑問なのがなぜ、Musicaというアプリが開くかということなんです。
Twitterから割り振られたIDが私どものIDとMusicaというアプリが同じだったからかなとも思ってしまいます。

Comment: @GO.tokyo IDが重複していればiTunesConnectでストア枠取れないはずなのでそれは無いかと、とはいえ、レビュワーさんがストア以外のアプリを入れていればわかりませんが。`Musica`というアプリは公開されているのですか？レビュワーさんに「現象を再現したいためこのアプリ(`Musica`)の配信URLをください」と尋ねてみてはどうでしょう？それをいれて試験してみては？

Comment: @Sieg様　ご丁寧に回答ありがとうございます。確かにそうですね。すでに、動画は共有しているので合わせて、配信URLの確認をしてみます。助かります。ありがとうございます。

Comment: @Sieg様　無事審査通りました。動画と画像をエビデンスで添付しましたところ、今度は黒い面がでるといわれてしまいましたがこれも同様に動画と画像を添付しこちらでは発生しないといったところ何の返信もなくインレビューから公開されました。
今後は、同様のトラブルがあった場合には同じことを試してみたいと思います。
本当にありがとうございました。

Comment: @GO.tokyo 審査が通ったようでよかったです。要はレビュワーが問題ないか確認できれば良いので問題あるなしに関わらず最初の申請時に動画を送ってしまうのが一番手っ取り早いです。解決したようでしたら、回答左側のチェックマークから回答の承認をお願いします。